# Can I use GCS and Cloud Sql APIs from normal Web Application (not GAE app)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Can I create normal java web application (not a GAE application) to use google cloud storage or cloud SQL APIs????
For example: create instance in cloud SQL, export database, etc..
I follow this startup application [a link](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/api-lib/java), but it is GAE app and what I need to develop is a normal web application.
Can any one help me please..

Answer (score 0):

For Cloud SQL, please take a look at the [Cloud SQL API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-api/index). Specifically you may want to check the [Java Library](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta3/api-lib/java).

Comment: Thank you. I already use the java library after I download the startup app (as I mention in my question), but I need to know Is it possible to  create web application and use the library from there instead of use it from GAE app.

Comment: oYou may have been looking at storage-serviceaccount-appengine-sample, which is appengine. The other two examples are not.

Comment: I'm trying now commandeLine-sample. This is what I need.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Cloud SQL instances from any application using standard connectors -- see https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external